# Received 'locking the remote repository failed' while attempting to clone a mercurial repo on local server

Tags: git, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

I got this error, "locking the remote repository failed", while trying to clone a repository using MercurialEclipse.   I've attempted this several times, always with the same result, but have successfully cloned several other repos from this same server.

Answer (score 0):

After searching the web, I came across an article which suggested that the problem may be attempting to do an clone with the --uncompressed option.  I checked my clone dialog in eclipse, and I had had that option set since the server was on our LAN.  I deselected the option and it worked like a champ.

Apparently, if the server doesn't have permission to lock the repository, it is unable to service an uncompressed clone request.  This is definitely not intuitive (to me) so I thought I'd share it here.

I hope it helps the next person with this symptom…
The original article can be found [here](http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/Something-wrong-with-selenic-com-repos-abort-locking-the-remote-repository-failed-td790120.html).